# React Native: How to open OS settings in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, settings

I am developing a **mobile** application using **React Native** in which I want to open mobile device's **settings** when user **clicks** on a specific button.

I have gone through the **docs** of RN, but still **couldn’t find** anything that can help me in achieving the same. Can someone **guide** me on the same, how can that be implemented?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Did you try to use Linking component form react-native (v0.60+)?

```
import { Button, Linking } from "react-native";

const Screen = () => (
  <Button
    title="Open Settings"
    onPress={() => {
      Linking.openSettings();
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: I tried this. "Linking.openSettings();" goes to App settings, but it doesn't go to phone settings.

Answer (score 16):

As an addition to [Rafael Perozin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10811863/rafael-perozin)'s answer.

On **Android** you can also send an **Intent** via **Linking**.

```
import { Button, Linking } from "react-native";

const Screen = () => (
  <Button
    title="Open Settings"
      onPress={() => {
      Platform.OS === 'ios' 
        ? Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Bluetooth')
        : Linking.sendIntent("android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS");
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I would like to send the user to **Bluetooth settings** and the [CR7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486377/10811863) answer didn't work for me.

So, I solved the problem using:

- **IOS:** `Linking` from `react-native`
- **ANDROID:** `AndroidOpenSettings` from [`react-native-android-open-settings`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-open-settings)

And I also used the `Platform` from `react-native` to check if the current device is an IOS.

See the code:

```js
...
import {Linking, Platform} from 'react-native';
import AndroidOpenSettings from 'react-native-android-open-settings';
...

...
const goToSettings = () =>
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Bluetooth')
    : AndroidOpenSettings.bluetoothSettings();
...

...
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => goToSettings()}>
  <Text>Go to settings</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
);
...
```

Comment: Did your iOS app get approved in the App Store with this?

Comment: It is ideal! `AndroidOpenSettings.securitySettings()`, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 4):

You can try the below code, "android.settings.SETTINGS" which can help you jump to the os setting screen.

```
import {Linking } from 'react-native'
Linking.sendIntent("android.settings.SETTINGS");
```